# Typeahead/Bloodhound dupDetector for Multiple Datasets

Tags: autocomplete, typeahead, bloodhound

I have two Bloodhound datasets, a local and a remote. The local data will always be duplicated in the remote results. I've found the dupDetector method mentioned in Typeahead documentation, but it seems this method only works if both my local and remote datasets are built within the same Bloodhound object.

Here's my code. Is there a way to filter duplicates across multiple Bloodhound datasets?

```
    var local_props = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function (p) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(p.name);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: portfolio_props,
        limit: 100
    });

    var remote_props = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: 'properties/searchPropertiesLike?substr=%QUERY',
        dupDetector: function(remoteMatch, localMatch) {
            return remoteMatch.name === localMatch.name;
        },
        limit: 100
    });

    local_props.initialize();
    remote_props.initialize();

    $('#typeahead-property').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'port_properties',
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: local_props.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            header: '<h3>Your Portfolio Properties</h3>'
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'dir_properties',
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: remote_props.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            header: '<h3>Properties Directory</h3>'
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you please create a sample on http://jsfiddle.net ?